# Reconstruct function based on Seed value and output

Tags: c#, prng

I have a program that I am re-writing in C#.  There is a function that I do not have the code for that I would like to recreate in the re-write.  Based on my investigation I believe that it is an RNG of some sort.

I have isolated the seed value and output of the function.  It generates an unsigned integer (seed) on program startup and then produces a 256 uint array based on that seed.  The program uses the values in the array and once the program reaches the end of the array the seed increments by 1 and the output of the array changes.

What I have tried:  I've set up tests using the algorithms for all the popular(?) RNG/PRNG methods that I could find (mersenne twister, xor32, etc).  I figured they might have used one of these when creating the function but have failed to reproduce the output.

My question is, if I have the output and the seed, is there a way to reproduce the function that produced this output?  I want to recreate it if possible.

Comment: The seed is always the same?  if the seed doesn't change, why not just create a static array, or just store it in a DB?  why generate it everytime if its always the same?

Comment: The seed does change, after it goes through the array values to the end the seed increases by 1 and the array is built again with new values.  Sorry for the confusion.  Edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Can't you port the exact code?

Comment: @usr - Unfortunately I don't have the code for this part application.  So I have to try and recreate what they did originally.

Comment: Ok you have a nasty reverse engineering task on your hands. Can you look at the disassembly (or is it managed code)? Without looking at code or disassembly you basically have lost.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of, yes I can look at the disassembly.  I managed to glean the information I have so far from a mix of using a disassembler and looking at the memory map.  I'm not very familiar with disassemblers or reverse engineering so I may just rewrite the entire thing from the ground up.